# Parsing spinner1's current item inside of spinner2's listener

Tags: android, android-spinner

How can I get spinner1's position inside of spinner2's onItemSelected listener so that I can convert to a string and parse for a calculation?

I am currently attempting to call adapterSpinner2.getItemAtPosition() inside of spinner1 but am getting an: Invalid float: "" logcat error. on the line where I am trying to call adapterSpinner2.

I know that my array that I am calling is all numbers, so it should not be simply an empty field error. My parse of spinner1 inside of spinner1's onItemSelected listener works fine so I believe it is in where I am trying to call spinner2.

Sorry if that is a bit confusing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

Spinner atmosphereSpinner;
Spinner pressurelossSpinner;

String AtmosphereSpinner;
String PressureLossSpinner;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    atmosphereSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.atmosphereSpinner);
    pressurelossSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.pressurelossSpinner);

    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterAtmosphere = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.atmosphere_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterPressureLoss = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.pressure_loss_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    atmosphereSpinner.setAdapter(adapterAtmosphere);
    pressurelossSpinner.setAdapter(adapterPressureLoss);

    atmosphereSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l){


            AtmosphereSpinner = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            float atmosphere = Float.parseFloat(AtmosphereSpinner);

            PressureLossSpinner = pressurelossSpinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            float pressureloss = Float.parseFloat(PressureLossSpinner);


            if (Boolean is True){
              //Do calculation
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }

    });

    pressurelossSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l){

            AtmosphereSpinner = atmosphereSpinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            float atmosphere = Float.parseFloat(AtmosphereSpinner);

            PressureLossSpinner = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            float pressureloss = Float.parseFloat(PressureLossSpinner);

            if (Boolean is true){
             //Do calculation
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }

    });
```

Logcat:

```
07-25 11:53:16.142      858-858/com.example.jstazak.ctsleaktester E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
            at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
            at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:289)
            at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
            at com.example.FragmentA$2.onItemSelected(FragmentA.java:97)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
            at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Line 63 is this line:                 PressureLossSpinner = pressurelossSpinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
```

Comment: Where is the code? Where is the logcat output?

Comment: Sorry, I will add that. I thought this would have been a general question that I was just missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In second spinner `onItemSelected` do this

```
AtmosphereSpinner = atmosphereSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

You can get the value of first spinner which is selected

Instead of

```
AtmosphereSpinner = atmosphereSpinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
```

**EDIT :**

1.Place String to float conversion in try catch. If exception occur it will go to catch block. There assign those floats `0.0f` else try to convert it `double` instead of `float`.

2.Code snippet for `String` to `float` conversion in spinners' `onItemSelected`

```
atmosphereSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l){
            float atmosphere; // It is better if you declare these 2 variables globally
            float pressureloss ;

            AtmosphereSpinner = atmosphereSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(!AtmosphereSpinner.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                atmosphere = Float.parseFloat(AtmosphereSpinner);
            else
                atmosphere = 0.0f;

            PressureLossSpinner = pressurelossSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(!PressureLossSpinner.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                pressureloss = Float.parseFloat(PressureLossSpinner);
            else
                pressureloss = 0.0f;

            if (Boolean is True){
              //Do calculation
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }

    });
```

> Do the same for second spinner also

Comment: Ah, thank-you. It is always something simple that I overlook.

Comment: How can I return my parsed value from a try/catch statement inside of the voided method?

Comment: Excellent, thank-you. Still learning, but you've helped a ton!