# Double.parseDouble(EditText) always throws NUllPointerException. How to solve?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, double

I want to get a double value from a `EditText` where you can only instert numberDecimal and numberSigned.

I thought:

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1)

double double1 = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
```

**But** logcat says that this `double = ""` and the app crashes

**Logcat:**

```
08-29 20:52:24.148  22688-22688/test.com.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  
ComponentInfo{test.com.app/test.com.app.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:244)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
        at test.com.app.Graph.yWerte(Graph.java:188)
        at test.com.app.Graph.getDataFromReceiver(Graph.java:184)
        at test.com.app.Main.onCreate(Main.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)       
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's `value` ? Show the log command too.

Comment: post full err msg. for `double = ""` u can [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959951/parsing-spinner1s-current-item-inside-of-spinner2s-listener/24961492#24961492)

Comment: Obviously `editText1.getText().toString()` is null. Are you calling this code *after* you enter code in the `EditText`?

Comment: Are you actually calling `Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString())` right after you defined the `EditText`? If so, then your error makes complete sense. You're trying to get the value from the `EditText` that was literally just defined and has no value set to it. You need to call `getText()` after some callback from a `Button` or something.

Comment: @Brian it is in a method which gets called through a button

Comment: The first step is to describe the problem correctly. It isn't that Double.parseDouble() 'is always null', it is that it always *throws* a NullPointerException, which can only mean that you are always *passing* it a null value. In other words the problem has nothing to do with Double.parseDouble() at all.

Comment: I agree with EJP. Also, I solved the NullPointerException problem and then you asked about why the code raises a NumberFormatException. Theoretically speaking, that's another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`editText1.getText()` is `null`. Try this:

```
CharSequence cs = editText1.getText();
double double1 = cs == null ? -1.0 : Double.parseDouble(cs.toString());
```

If you want to avoid also the `NumberFormatException` in case you typed a non-parsable double, you can write:

```
double double1 = -1.0; // invalid!
try {
    double1 = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
} catch(RuntimeException ignored) {
    // NPE or parsing failed, double1 == -1.0
}
```

Catching (and also ignoring) `RuntimeException`s is not good practice in general, but it is ok in this example due to the particular API.

Edit: updated after the stack trace has been posted

Edit 2: updated to correct also the parsing problem

Comment: That's another problem, it should be another question, but let me update my code to solve it.

Comment: I had forgotten the assignment. It should work fine now, as long as you input a valid double in the EditText